# Elasticsearch.NET & NEST - search always returning 0 results

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I'm trying to search using the `ElasticClient.Search` method but no matter what terms I set, or field I search by, I always get 0 results.

Here is the structure of my POCO:

```
public class MyParent
{
    public MyChild MyChild { get; set; }
}

public class MyChild
{
    public string MyField { get; set; }
}
```

And then here is my actual search code:

```
string searchTerm = "myChild.myField";
string searchValue = "C";

Field searchField = new Field(searchTerm);

ISearchResponse<MyParent> result =
    Client.Search<MyParent>(s =>
        s.Query(q => q.Term(searchField, searchValue)));

if (result != null && 
    result.Documents != null && 
    result.Documents.Count != 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I would get the raw query that is executed (from your result object) and run it in kibana

Comment: Can you please tell me where inside the `ISearchResponse<MyParent>` object I get the raw query from?

Comment: also check is the result is successful and if there is an error message

Comment: It is "Successful low level call on POST" but I don't see the raw query

Comment: `var query = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.RequestInformation.Request);`

Comment: Ty! apparently the raw query for ES6 is `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes);`

Comment: my guess would be that it does not return anything... try a Match query instead of Term

Comment: Match doesn't work and the raw query looks fine. I tried it out in Kibana and the query works there so... I don't get it

Comment: Use fiddler to sniff the raw http and look at what is different when you use Elastic console

Comment: Thanks all! Found the issue (posted as an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I wasn't setting the index! I changed my search code to this and it works:

```
ISearchResponse<MyParent> result =
    Client.Search<MyParent>(s =>
        s.Index("my_index_").Query(q => q.Term(searchField, searchValue)));
```